How to hide a frameless electron window on blur
I'm writing an electron app that should be shown when clicking on it's tray icon, and should be hidden when clicking outside of the window.
This is how I created the window:
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  frame: false,
  width: 375,
  height: 574,
  icon: getAssetPath('icon.png'),
  alwaysOnTop: true,
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: true,
    nodeIntegration: false,
    preload: app.isPackaged
      ? path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
      : path.join(__dirname, '../../.erb/dll/preload.js'),
  },
});

This is the tray click handler:
tray.on('click', () => {
  if (mainWindow?.isVisible()) {
    mainWindow?.hide();
  } else {
    mainWindow?.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'modal-panel');
    mainWindow?.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true, {
      visibleOnFullScreen: true,
    });
    mainWindow?.show();
  }
});

And this is the blur handler, where I try to achieve the requested behavior:
mainWindow.on('blur', () => {
  mainWindow?.hide();
});

When I click on the tray icon the frameless window is shown as expected, but when I move my mouse from the tray icon the blur event is triggered, thus hiding the mainWindow.
The blur event is also fired whenever I hover over the toolbar, which probably makes it focused.
How can I achieve this behavior?
